# Why does the function fail to parse the data from a csv file when another function works to parse the csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
def participated():
   part_counters = {}
   for line in reader:
       if int(line[6]) > 0:
           primary = line[7].strip()
           part_counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
           part_counters[primary] += 1

        return part_counters


data_out.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(data_out)
next(reader,None)


def generalNumber():
    gen_counters = {}
    for line in reader:
        if int(line[6]) >= 0:
            primary = line[7].strip()
            gen_counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
            gen_counters[primary] += 1

    return gen_counters
```

I have 2 functions that try to parse out the same data from the same csv file. I've put this`data_out.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(data_out)
next(reader,None)`
 which worked for each function to parse it but then it won't work if the variables are outside of the function. I am trying to use the `return value` from each function outside such as:

```
counter_p = participated()
counter_g = generalNumber()
success_percentage = [counter_p.get(primary)/counter_g.get(primary, 1) for primary in counter_p]
```

What I have is that is that if both functions are active: `counter_p = {A01:5, A02:1, A03:2}` and `counter_g ={}` but if I make participated() inactive then `counter_g = {A01: 6, A02: 3, A03: 5}`

Comment: You are consuming the file in each method, that is why you need to obtain the reader before each method call. The second method call returns an empty dictionary because the reader reached the end of the file, as the first method call ended.

Comment: How would I be able to restart the reader for the second method so it doesn't return the empty dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't do global resources.

Long answer: `reader` is an iterator, which iterates over the lines in your csv. That is, whenever a new line has been provided, the iterator skips on to the next line. That implies that it will reach the last line somewhen, and cannot provide any more lines then (since there aren't any).

The first time either of your functions uses `reader`, the entire content of the csv is consumed. Afterwards, `reader` is at the end of the file. Calling another function that uses `reader` thus cannot get any more lines from it.

You have two obvious solutions here:

1. Rewind `data_out` via `data_out.seek(0)` every time you exhaust `reader`. This is already done by your code:

   ```
   data_out.seek(0)
   reader = csv.reader(data_out)
   next(reader,None)
   ```

   Now, since you use `reader` as a global resource, this is done only once at the moment. You'd have to repeat `data_out.seek(0)` at the end of both `generalNumber` and `participated`. Even then, this may not work correctly, as file and iterator are separate, but you get the idea hopefully.
2. Open the file for every time you want to read it. Ideally, both of your functions just take a file name, open that file, iterate over it, and close it again. This way, you get a new, fresh iterator every time.

   ```
   def generalNumber(file_name):
     with open(file_name) as data_out:  # open the file, implicitly at first line
       reader = csv.reader(data_out)  # create new iterator
       next(reader,None)  # replicated from your code
       gen_counters = {}
       for line in reader:
         if int(line[6]) >= 0:
           primary = line[7].strip()
           gen_counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
           gen_counters[primary] += 1
     return gen_counters
   ```